# Cocos2D isTouchEnabled = NO; scene release and crash

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, exc-bad-access

I'm working on an iPhone game using cocos2d and I'm new to Objective C and Cocos2d so I'm sorry if this is a really beginner question. I've done a lot of searching and I can't seem to find a solution for this problem. I've found that cocos2d will not call the dealloc function, release a scene, or a layer unless I put `-(void) onExit{self.isTouchEnabled = NO;}` at the end of the `.m` file. The problem is that in the next scene the game crashes when the screen is touched, even if I put `self.isTouchEnabled = YES;` in the `init` method, `onEnter`method, or anywhere else within the second scene.

When the game crashes (gbd) points to:

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if( dispatchEvents )
        [self touches:touches withEvent:event withTouchType:kCCTouchBegan];
}`

as the source of the problem stating "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Please help!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

I am new to iPhone as well:-) But for my experiences, the reason you get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" is not because of your code here. it should be "**release**" problem. i guess you release a released object...

you can try to use Xcode's Zombies instruments to detect where you get this problem. There are heaps of tutorials about Xcode Zombies online, just google it if you want.

good luck:-)